# Mini sudoku solver in Prolog stops partway through

Tags: prolog, sudoku, clpfd

I'm working through 'Seven Languages in Seven Weeks', and I'm just trying to get an example from the book working. It solves a mini sudoku grid (4x4).

The author is using gprolog, but I am using swi-prolog (I couldn't get gprolog to work on my VM for whatever reason, but swi-prolog worked first try).

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 in VirtualBox 4.0.4 r70112 (hopefully that's not too relevant!)

Here is the code in my prolog file:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

valid([]).
valid([Head|Tail]) :-
    all_different(Head),    % in the book, this is 'fd_all_different'
    valid(Tail).

 % beginning of sudoku rule itself
sudoku(Puzzle, Solution) :- 
Solution = Puzzle,
Puzzle = [S11, S12, S13, S14,
          S21, S22, S23, S24,
          S31, S32, S33, S34,
          S41, S42, S43, S44],
Puzzle ins 1..4,    % in the book, this is 'fd_domain'

Row1 = [S11, S12, S13, S14],
Row2 = [S21, S22, S23, S24],
Row3 = [S31, S32, S33, S34],
Row4 = [S41, S42, S43, S44],

Col1 = [S11, S21, S31, S41],
Col2 = [S12, S22, S32, S42],
Col3 = [S13, S23, S33, S43],
Col4 = [S14, S24, S34, S44],

Square1 = [S11, S12, S21, S22],
Square2 = [S13, S14, S23, S24],
Square3 = [S31, S32, S41, S42],
Square4 = [S33, S34, S43, S44],

valid([Row1, Row2, Row3, Row4,
       Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,
       Square1, Square2, Square3, Square4]).
```

The only parts that I (intentionally) changed were:

- adding `use_module(library(clpfd)).` at the top
- changing `fd_all_different(Head),` to `all_different(Head),`
- changing `fd_domain(Puzzle, 1, 4),` to `Puzzle ins 1..4,`

Here is the invocation from swipl

```
?- sudoku([_, _, 2, 3,
           _, _, _, _,
           _, _, _, _,
           3, 4, _, _],
Solution).
Solution = [4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1|...] ;
false.
```

The solution is correct right up until it cuts off, at which point prolog seems to determine that there is no solution. But there is:

```
4 1 2 3
2 3 4 1
1 2 3 4
3 4 1 2
```

I've scoured the code looking for a typo or misplaced column, but have been unable to find the source of this. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `:- use_module(library(clpfd))`?

Comment: Yes, it should be, thanks. I guess I had loaded the library earlier right into swipl, and it didn't error out on that (until I quit and reran it). Unfortunately even once it is fixed it still gives the same result.

Comment: That part where it leaves off is where Prolog stops showing the elements in the array, but it's still there. You'll have to write an additional predicate to help you display all the elements in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me you are relying on the default display in SWI-Prolog to write the list that represents the solution, and it's a feature of SWI-Prolog that it doesn't print all the entries of a long list in this case, replacing the tail after nine items with the "ellipsis" ...

You stumbled onto this when you added `write(Puzzle)` to the goal and thus saw the entire list.  SWI-Prolog's site [has a FAQ about this "abbreviation" of lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html).

Comment: Thank you, that is very good to know! Changing the default of max_depth using the statement suggested in the FAQ you linked works perfectly!

Comment: @Nick Knowlson: Note the other "on the fly" way to do this is by hitting "w" instead of ";".  That forces the top-level interpreter to spit out the full list (or structure, since it's really a limitation on nested depth that affects the display).

Comment: I would do that, but after I quit swipl and reloaded it (to verify that I fixed my module importing syntax) it finishes and gives me the solution (whether it is fully done or only partway) without prompting me now. Probably because it can now tell that there is only one solution for this particular query? I will remember that for the future though.

Comment: @Nick Knowlson:  You probably want to write a little predicate to display the "sudoku" grid in its familiar layout (as shown in your last "code" section).  Certainly it makes it more readable for even the 4x4 case, not to mention the difficulty of parsing a 9x9 grid in simple list format.

Comment: That is actually the next step in these problems! :) I wanted to make sure I understood what was happening before I moved on. And I agree, I sure wouldn't want to see if I was getting the right solutions by reading a flat list of 81 numbers!

Answer (score 2):

You typed in the `;` yourself, didn't you? `;` asks for more solutions. Since you didn't use `labeling` on the variables, Prolog only constrains them without actually generating a complete solution (it does some [constraint propagation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Local_consistency) to derive a few of the values). There's only one way to put the constraints, so there's no second solution. If you put a call to `labeling` at the end of the `sudoku` clause, you can cycle through the solutions.

(PS.: `sudoku` doesn't need two arguments, since you unify them with `Solution = Puzzle`.)

Comment: Yeah, I typed the `;` myself, probably should have included that. I understand that there is no second solution. Actually, after rerunning it in a fresh swipl the output looks a little different, it gives just the one answer without asking me if I want to look for more. I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying when you say 'put a call to `labeling` at the end'.

Comment: Good point about not needing two arguments. Actually, as soon as I changed it to use one argument instead and added `write(Puzzle)` at the end, it printed out the whole thing! Why did this happen?

Comment: So, if I wanted to keep it the previous way and use `labeling`, what would that entail? I looked at the docs and tried adding `label(Solution)` at the end, but it didn't change anything. This is if it were still using two parameters (for the sake of curiosity)

Comment: @Nick: in this case, the solution may be fully determined by the constraints, but in general you need a call to `labeling` or `label` to actually search for solutions in a constraint problem. Of course, if there is only one solution, `labeling` will find no second one.

Comment: That is good to know, that in general I need a call to labeling or label in constraint problems. I did make a call to `label` as I said in my last comment, but I must be 'doing it wrong' because it still only returned part of the solution.