# How to trace backtracks of clpfd in prolog?

Tags: prolog, sudoku, clpfd

I am making a `sudoku` solver with `prolog` using `clpfd library`. I have to trace the backtracks and every squares labeled with row and column and the number it gets in the following form:

```
(1 ,1 ,1)              
(9 ,2 ,1)              
BT
(5 ,2 ,1)
```

My question is how can I get the above information from the algorithm?

Another question: Does the algorithm observe `arc-consistency` rules by itself?

Comment: Why do you need traces in the first place? And, arc-consistency is observed by clpfd, trivially.

Comment: All I need is to know which variable takes which value in every step of the algorithm. Tracing was the first idea came to my mind.

Comment: You can observe a lot and without tracing at the [tag:prolog-toplevel] by simply issuing queries with partially instantiated arguments.

Comment: Thanks. What about backtracking? How to know when does the algorithm backtrack?

Comment: That's very difficult - and pretty pointless: the very precise kind of consistency is much more important.

Comment: I did not find any proper code to find every time a value assigned to a variable. could you please tell me how to do this? I am using a code like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617126/mini-sudoku-solver-in-prolog-stops-partway-through?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a particularly good idea, but here is something using SWI-Prolog's attributed variables that prints the bindings of a set of variables whenever one of them becomes bound:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

% Vars is a list of Name-Variable pairs where Variable is a free variable
% and Name is an atom or some other identifier for the variable.
trace_vars(Vars) :-
    maplist(trace_var(Vars), Vars).

trace_var(Vars, Id-V) :-
    when(ground(V), print_new_binding(Vars, Id-V)).

print_new_binding(Vars, Id-V) :-
    format('new binding ~w, all bindings now: ~w~n', [Id-V, Vars]).
```

You can use this to "trace" things, in a sense:

```
?- Vars = [a-A,b-B,c-C], trace_vars(Vars), [A,B,C] ins 0..1, A #< B, B #< C.
new binding a-0, all bindings now: [a-0,b-_G211,c-_G217]
new binding b-1, all bindings now: [a-0,b-1,c-_G217]
false.
```

This only prints new bindings, including for variables that were bound before, but it does *not* print the moment when variables become unbound on backtracking. That information is implicit (and would need ugly hacks to become explicit):

```
?- Vars = [a-A,b-B,c-C], trace_vars(Vars), [A,B,C] ins 0..1, labeling([], [A,B,C]).
new binding a-0, all bindings now: [a-0,b-_G208,c-_G214]
new binding b-0, all bindings now: [a-0,b-0,c-_G214]
new binding c-0, all bindings now: [a-0,b-0,c-0]
Vars = [a-0, b-0, c-0],
A = B, B = C, C = 0 ;
new binding c-1, all bindings now: [a-0,b-0,c-1]
Vars = [a-0, b-0, c-1],
A = B, B = 0,
C = 1 ;
new binding b-1, all bindings now: [a-0,b-1,c-_G214]
new binding c-0, all bindings now: [a-0,b-1,c-0]
Vars = [a-0, b-1, c-0],
A = C, C = 0,
B = 1 ;
new binding c-1, all bindings now: [a-0,b-1,c-1]
Vars = [a-0, b-1, c-1],
A = 0,
B = C, C = 1 ;
new binding a-1, all bindings now: [a-1,b-_G208,c-_G214]
...
```

For your use case, use coordinates as identifiers in the `Vars` list, e.g., `[(1,1)-Var11, (1,2)-Var12, ...]`.

I don't think watching clpfd at work in this way will enlighten you, though.

**Edit:** As mat points out in the comments, adding a *failing* second clause to `print_new_binding/2` allows you to revisit a variable before its binding is undone:

```
print_new_binding(_Vars, Id-_V) :-
    format('undo binding for ~w~n', [Id]),
    false.
```

Comment: Instead of `when(ground(Var), Goal)`, consider using `freeze(Var, Goal)`. To show when a variable becomes *unbound* again, you only need a second clause for `Goal`, which prints "Variable is unbound" and then *fails*. On backtracking, you will see this emitted every time a binding is undone!

Comment: Awesome tip, thanks! I added an edit. Concerning `freeze/2` vs. `when/2`, I find the latter clearer to read. Are there any relevant differences between `freeze(Var, Goal)` and `when(nonvar(Var), Goal)`?

Comment: As I see it, a problem of `when/2` is that it can easily lead users to believe that a general condition like `when(Cond, ...)` is admissible, when in reality, the admissible conditions are very limited. In sufficiently advanced Prolog systems, such mistakes are easily detected and lead to a *domain error*, but previously, such a mistake could lead to hours and days of wading through traces, not knowing why the condition fails when it "obviously" holds. This happened to a friend, by the way ;-) `freeze/2` is less general, but suffices in this use case, and I would prefer the simpler construct.